# divide or multiply if number between 1 and 0

Tags: arithmetic

This is a math question in the context of an Excel spreadsheet. I have an Excel spreadsheet with 10 rows, where I am dividing the value in ColumnB by the value in ColumnA to create a new number like this

```
        A       B        New Number 
Bill    1.14    156      136.842  (156 / 1.14)
```

The new number ( as I call it ) is being used to compare each of the rows against each other i.e. I am sorting from biggest to smallest based on this "new number"

I am running into confusion when the number in columnA is less than 1. If it's less than 1 do I still divide by the value in ColumnA or do I multiply by the value in ColumnA? You can see from below, that the output will differ significantly

```
Mike    0.48   250      520 (250 / .48)
```

or

```
Mike    0.48   250      120 (250 * .48)
```

In my head, I am thinking that I must be stupid. If I divide by the value in ColumnA for the first 9 rows (where value in columnA is greater than 1), then I also have to do it for the 10th row (where value in columnA is less than 1), however, the total of `120` (reached by multiplying) makes more sense intuitively than the total of `520` (reached by dividing) that now I'm totally confused if different rules apply when the number is between 0 and 1 and I should indeed be multiplying.

Question 1: if the number for value in columnA is between 0 and 1, do I need to divide or multiply columnB by the value in ColumnA (if I want the sort comparison for all ten rows from greatest to least to make sense)

Part 2: if I do indeed need to multiply for that 1 row (and divide for all 9 others), is there a way in Excel to apply a formula to all 10 rows that takes into account that in one row the operator changes?

Sample Data

```
        ColumnA ColumnB  Total.
Mike    0.48   175       84       175 * .48  (Or do I still divide?
Bill    1.14    156      136.842  156 / 1.14
Simon   2.02    189      93.56    189 / 2.02
Jim     2.56    112      43.75    112 / 2.56
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve but yes if you divide by a number between 0 and 1 then obviously you get a higher value. In Excel you could make use of the if function with test clause Ax < 1, if you really wish to, and then divide by Ax or multiply with it based on Ax<1 being true or false.

Comment: @Maestro13 I think you misunderstood the question. I am asking "what am I required to do" by the laws of Math if my ultimate goal is to sort the list (i.e. compare the 10 rows) from greatest to least. If for the 9 rows where  I am dividing by the value in column A (where the value is greater than 1) am I required for the 10th row (where the value is between 0 and 1) to do the same (i.e. divide), or should I multiply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide you are basically asking the question: what percent is this number of another number? So when you divide 156 by 1.14, you are saying: 156 is 114% of what number? Well its 114% of 136.842. So If that's what you're trying to do, then don't change your formula unless instructed to by a book (if this is for homework) or a mentor to the project.

If you needed to have a condition taken into account (such as if the number was between 0 and 1) then you can use the =if() statement. In this case you would do =if(0

Comment: so by dividing 250 by .48 I'm asking what am I asking `250 is 50% of what number?`

Comment: Correct. In algebra I would set the problem up in proportions. So one one side I would have 250/.48 and then on the other x/1. Like:
250/.48=x/1 -->
250=.48X -->
X=520
so 250 is 48% of 520 which is 100%.
X=250/.48

Comment: just out of curiosity, what would question would I basically be asking if I multiplied instead of divided?

Comment: If you multiply a number by a percent (decimal) then you are asking something like this:
520*.48=250 This is basically saying: what is 48% of 520?